# Cannot Resolve The Symbol 'R' - After importing eclipse project to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-support-library

Please be gentle, I am moving my projects from Eclipse to Android Studio. The first issue is that all my activities now have problems resolving 'R'. I have a feeling that this is produced because the support library. Generally I am using only the v.4 library but now in android studio I get the following error:

> /Users/vedtam/StudioProjects/foto.studio/fotostudio/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/res/values-v11/values.xml Error:(47, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>
> /Users/vedtam/StudioProjects/foto.studio/fotostudio/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/res/values-v14/values.xml Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
>
> /Users/vedtam/StudioProjects/foto.studio/fotostudio/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/res/values-v21/values.xml Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
>   Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "foto.studio"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/braintree-api-1.6.1-full.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.4-SNAPSHOT.jar')
}
```

Why am I getting these errors if I don't have the v.7 support library between the dependecies?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some resources can't be resolved properly in values.xml for your various api versions from `values-v11, values-14 and values-21` in the res directory of your app. That's the reason for the not resolving "R" issue. Open those XML files and fix them then your AS will build fine.